# Math Puzzle: Totaling up A,B, C

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

We know the following about the numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$:

$$(a+b)^2=9,\quad(b+c)^2=25, \quad(a+c)^2=81$$

If $a + b + c ≥ 1$, determine the **number** of possible values for $a + b + c$

Comment: Is there any trick to this, or is it just straightforward counting of possibilities? Also, I assume you meant to specify $a,b,c$ must be integers?

Comment: There are different possibilities of a, b, and c, for e.g 0+3, and 1+2.

Answer (score 7):

We know that:

> $$a+b=\pm 3\\b+c=\pm5\\a+c=\pm9$$

It then follows that

> by adding them up we get
>  $$ 2(a+b+c) = \pm3\pm5\pm9 $$
>  Since $a+b+c\ge1$, we need this to be greater or equal to $2$.

So the question boils down to finding

> how many choices of the signs make $\pm3\pm5\pm9 \ge2$ true.
>  Clearly $9$ cannot have a minus sign, so we have $9\pm3\pm5 \ge2$. This only fails when both remaining signs are minus signs, so there are three possibilities left.

The solutions are therefore:

> $$a+b+c = (9+3+5)/2 = 17/2\\a+b+c = (9+3-5)/2 = 7/2\\a+b+c = (9-3+5)/2 = 11/2$$